# Equivalent definition of $\text{limsup}$

Tags: definition

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a sequence. On some texts the definition of $\text{limsup}$ is as follows:

> **Definition 1.**
>   $$\text{limsup}x_n=\inf_{k\ge1}\bigg(\sup_{n\ge k}x_n\bigg)$$

while other texts other texts give the following definition

> **Definition 2.** $$\text{limsup}x_n=\inf_{k\ge 0}\bigg(\sup_{n\ge k}x_n\bigg)$$

---

> **Question** Are the two definitions equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on what is the starting value of $n$ (or $k$), that is whether $N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the definition depends on whether your definition of $\Bbb N$ includes zero or not, i.e. if the first index of a sequence is $0$ or $1$.  But it makes no difference  even if $\Bbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$:
For each $k$ is
$$
\sup_{n\ge k+1}x_n \le \sup_{n\ge k}x_n 
$$
because the supremum of a smaller set is taken on the left-hand side.
In other words, the sequence
$$
\bigg(\sup_{n\ge k}x_n\bigg)_k
$$
is *decreasing,* and it's infimum (which is equal to its limit for $k\to \infty$) does not depend on whether the term for $k=0$ is included or not.